# Laravel 5.4 Проблема с проверкой прав в сервис-провайдере

Tags: php, laravel, auth, permissions, role

Делаю учебный проект - корпоративный сайт. В курсе версия фреймворка 5.2, но я опрометчиво решил делать тоже самое на 5.4

В сервис-провайдере app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php в методе boot() следующий код:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('VIEW_ADMIN', function ($user){
            return $user->canDo('VIEW_ADMIN');
        });
    }
```

Метод canDo() не определен в провайдере и если код выполнялся бы, то я бы видел соответствующее исключение, но его нет. Он просто игнорируется. Хотя в документации такая же конструкция используется (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization). Подскажите, где я допустил оплошность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сервис-провайдере вы только устанавливаете права, но не проверяете, в вашем случае просто записалось правило с названием `VIEW_ADMIN` и анонимная функция, но она не выполняется.

Вот если бы вы потом где то обратились к этому правилу:

```
if (Gate::allows('VIEW_ADMIN')) {
    // Ваше действие
}
```

Вот тогда бы вызвалась ваша анонимная функция и отработал код:

```
$user->canDo('VIEW_ADMIN');
```

Не дочитали вы немного документацию, остановились на определении правил.

Comment: А описывать данный метод надо тоже в сервис-провайдере?

Comment: @JohnRoget какой именно? Если вы про `canDo`, так это ваш же метод который вызывается в классе `User`